# make isoimage fails with 160 error

Tags: kernel, make, livecd

I am trying to build a new kernel (more details later) to use in a pxe boot. I ran the make, so now I am trying to run make isoimage so I can rip the need files. Here is my attempt with the error. Any thoughts on what the recipe needs?

```
bradmin@LinuxDebianLive:/home/kernelbuild/linux-4.12.2$ sudo make isoimage
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  SKIPPED include/generated/compile.h
  LD      arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux
  ZOFFSET arch/x86/boot/zoffset.h
  AS      arch/x86/boot/header.o
  LD      arch/x86/boot/setup.elf
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/setup.bin
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
  BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
Setup is 17692 bytes (padded to 17920 bytes).
System is 4079 kB
CRC 55a16ccf
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
rm -rf arch/x86/boot/isoimage
mkdir arch/x86/boot/isoimage
for i in lib lib64 share end ; do \
        if [ -f /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin ] ; then \
                cp /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin arch/x86/boot/isoimage ; \
                if [ -f /usr/$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 ]; then \
                        cp /usr/$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 arch/x86/boot/isoimage ; \
                fi ; \
                break ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ $i = end ] ; then exit 1 ; fi ; \
done
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:160: recipe for target 'isoimage' failed
make[1]: *** [isoimage] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:286: recipe for target 'isoimage' failed
make: *** [isoimage] Error 2
bradmin@LinuxDebianLive:/home/kernelbuild/linux-4.12.2$
```

The more info .. I post a question on wrong forum ... [Link to why I am trying to build a kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154258/why-udpcpc-when-pxe-booting-is-not-setting-an-ip-address?noredirect=1#comment77320332_45154258)
I started with the live Clonezilla iso. It would not dhcp while pxe booting. Someone suggested the kernel might be the issue. So that is where I am. While making the make .config, I found parameters to enable dhcp support under the IP: kernel level autoconfiguration, so that may get me over the hump. So when I started to build the iso with make isoimage, that is when it failed, and that is where I current am.

Update:
I added some echos into the script for some diagnostic.
Look like it is not finding isolinux.bin or ldlinux.c32. 
if I was more experiance I might have seen what was happening, I thought since I saw the done, that part was finished. Now I see the logic and by hitting the end, that was throwing the exit 1 (error).

script change

```
isoimage: $(obj)/bzImage
    -rm -rf $(obj)/isoimage
    mkdir $(obj)/isoimage
    echo Start of loop
    for i in lib lib64 share end ; do \
        echo $$i; \
        if [ -f /usr/$$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin ] ; then \
            cp /usr/$$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin $(obj)/isoimage ; \
            if [ -f /usr/$$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 ]; then \
                cp /usr/$$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 $(obj)/isoimage ; \
            fi ; \
            break ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ $$i = end ] ; then echo "(isolinux.bin or ldlinux.c32) not found"; exit 1 ; fi ; \
    done
    echo start of copy
    cp $(obj)/bzImage $(obj)/isoimage/linux
```

Output :

```
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
rm -rf arch/x86/boot/isoimage
mkdir arch/x86/boot/isoimage
echo Start of loop
Start of loop
for i in lib lib64 share end ; do \
    echo $i; \
        if [ -f /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin ] ; then \
                cp /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin arch/x86/boot/isoimage ; \
                if [ -f /usr/$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 ]; then \
                        cp /usr/$i/syslinux/ldlinux.c32 arch/x86/boot/isoimage ; \
                fi ; \
                break ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ $i = end ] ; then echo "(isolinux.bin or ldlinux.c32) not found"; exit 1 ; fi ; \
done
lib
lib64
share
end
(isolinux.bin or ldlinux.c32) not found
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:160: recipe for target 'isoimage' failed
make[1]: *** [isoimage] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:286: recipe for target 'isoimage' failed
make: *** [isoimage] Error 2
bradmin@LinuxDebianLive:/home/kernelbuild/linux-4.12.2$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will likely work if you download and use syslinux instead of `make isoimage`. See ["How Can I Make a Bootable CD With ISOLINUX?"](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISOLINUX#How_Can_I_Make_a_Bootable_CD_With_ISOLINUX.3F) for more info. Also depending on your distro you may want to use `genisoimage` instead of `mkisofs` (the options are quite the same though).

Your distro may have a customized syslinux which is different what's expected. Ubuntu is known to do such thing for example...